# Adding lines to a textbox through code while keeping the previous lines? C#

Tags: c#

I am using a basic textbox and the program is coded in c#, I currently am having a generator generate strings which are to be outputted onto the Textbox for the user, however I want the previous lines that were generated to stay visible to the user instead of replacing the old generated string with the new one.

```
//Random generator
        Random rnd = new Random();

        //Int
        int Player1_Attack = rnd.Next(1, 11);

        String p1_attack = Player1_Attack.ToString();

        if (Player1_Attack == 4 || Player1_Attack == 6 || Player1_Attack == 8 || Player1_Attack == 10) {

            txt_combat.Text = "\nYou have Struck your opponent!";

        }

        if (Player1_Attack == 2)
        {
            txt_combat.Text = "\nYou landed a Critical Attack!";

        }

        else
        {

            txt_combat.Text = "\nSigh... your attack missed.";

        }
```

Comment: Did you tried `.Text += "...";`?

Comment: Is this Windows Forms or ASP.NET (or I guess it could even be WPF or Silverlight)? C# is not specific enough... I ask because `txt_combat.AppendText()` might be more efficient: [TextBox.Text += "string"; vs TextBox.AppendText("string");](//stackoverflow.com/q/20632372)

Answer (score 0):

```
txt_combat.Text = txt_combat.Text + "\r\nYou landed a critical attack!";
```

or for short:

```
txt_combat.Text += "\r\nYou landed a critical attack!";
```

Both do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **+=** operator instead of this **=** operator.

```
string Name = "MyName";

Name = "Tornike";

Console.WriteLine(Name) // Output will be Tornike

Name += "Tornike";

Console.WriteLine(Name) // Output will be MyNameTornike
```